# SQLite recursive query to return the ID of a given Path

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursive-query

I'm storing a hierarchy of folders in an Sqlite Database like so:

```
+----------+---------+----------+
| ParentID | ChildID |   Name   |
+----------+---------+----------+
|        1 |       2 | Folder A |
|        2 |       3 | Folder B |
|        3 |       4 | Folder C |
+----------+---------+----------+
```

Where `Folder A` is the root and the structure is: `Folder A/Folder B/Folder C`.

Currently, I have a Recursive CTE that can derive the *path of a folder given its ID*. (It works by finding the ID in the ChildID column and then walking upward)

However, what I DON'T currently have is a way to derive *the ID of a folder given its path*. This is definitely a bit trickier because I have to split the string on the `/` if I want to be able to query the table.

So far I have the start of the Recursive CTE:

```
SELECT Path, ChildID FROM DirectoryStructure, (
    SELECT SUBSTR('Folder A/Folder B/Folder C', 0, Position) as Root, 
           SUBSTR('Folder A/Folder B/Folder C', Position+1) as Path 
    FROM (SELECT INSTR('Folder A/Folder B/Folder C', '/') as Position)
) WHERE Name = Root
```

This will return:

```
+-------------------+---------+
|       Path        | ChildID |
+-------------------+---------+
| Folder B/Folder C |       2 |
+-------------------+---------+
```

This is perfect because I have the ChildID of `Folder A` and also have the next chunk of the Path to process. Now it should just be a matter of performing the next step recursively where I pluck off `Folder B` (like I did `Folder A`) and find the entry in `DirectoryStructure` where `ParentID = 2 AND Name = 'Folder B'` to get its `ChildID` and so on.

However, that's where I'm having trouble. I would imagine I need something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE GetId(Path, LastChild) AS (
    SELECT Path, ChildID FROM DirectoryStructure, (
        SELECT SUBSTR('Folder A/Folder B/Folder C', 0, Position) as Root, 
               SUBSTR('Folder A/Folder B/Folder C', Position+1) as Path 
        FROM (SELECT INSTR('Folder A/Folder B/Folder C', '/') as Position)
    ) WHERE Name = Root
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Path, ChildID FROM DirectoryStructure, (
        SELECT SUBSTR(GetId.Path, 0, Position) as Root, 
               SUBSTR(GetId.Path, Position+1) as Path
        FROM GetId, (SELECT INSTR(GetId.Path, '/') as Position FROM GetId)
    ) WHERE (ParentID = GetId.LastChild, Name = Root)
) SELECT * from GetId;
```

Playing around with this I usually get the error: `Result: recursive reference in a subquery: GetId`

I get that it doesn't want me using `GetId` in the subqueries but I can't seem to figure out any other way to accomplish this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just `SELECT * FROM DirectoryStructure WHERE 'Folder A/Folder B/Folder C' LIKE '%/' || Name`?

Comment: `DirectoryStructure` could contain folders of the same name with different IDs. This would technically work but it would give me all the folders that matched `Folder C` not the specific one specified by the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way of approaching this is to find the path to every child and then just compare against the search path:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
  SELECT ChildId, Name AS Path
  FROM DirectoryStructure
  WHERE ParentID = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.ChildId, Path || '/' || Name
  FROM DirectoryStructure d
  JOIN CTE ON d.ParentId = CTE.ChildId
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Path = 'Folder A/Folder B/Folder C'
```

Output:

```
ChildId     Path
4           Folder A/Folder B/Folder C
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oJ6KL1Xv1ahzLr1MjiyHFt/0)

If your table is large and the above query is too slow, you can prune the entries as you go to ensure that they match the desired path up to that level:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
  SELECT ChildId, Name AS Path
  FROM DirectoryStructure
  WHERE ParentID = 1
    AND 'Folder A/Folder B/Folder C' LIKE Name || '%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.ChildId, Path || '/' || Name
  FROM DirectoryStructure d
  JOIN CTE ON d.ParentId = CTE.ChildId
  WHERE 'Folder A/Folder B/Folder C' LIKE Path || '/' || Name || '%'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Path = 'Folder A/Folder B/Folder C'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oJ6KL1Xv1ahzLr1MjiyHFt/1)